# How to use Apify on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, apify

I'm deploying some code using Apify as Google Cloud Functions. When triggered, the Cloud Function terminates silently. What am I doing wrong?

I have some working code using Apify 0.15.1. It runs fine locally. Once deployed as a Google Cloud Function, it fails silently without any clear error. The equivalent code using Puppeteer 1.18.1 works fine.

I've reproduced the issue using more simple code below. While this example doesn't strictly require Apify, I would like to be able to use the extra functionality provided by Apify.

Code using Apify:

```
const Apify = require("apify");

exports.screenshotApify = async (req, res) => {
  let imageBuffer;
  Apify.main(async () => {
    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://xenaccounting.com");

    imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true });

    await browser.close();
  });

  if (res) {
    res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
    res.send(imageBuffer);
  }

  return imageBuffer;
};
```

Code using Puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

exports.screenshotPup = async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://xenaccounting.com");

  const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({ fullpage: true });

  await browser.close();

  if (res) {
    res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
    res.send(imageBuffer);
  }

  return imageBuffer;
};
```

Once deployed as a Google Cloud Function (with --trigger-http and --memory=2048), the Puppeteer variant works fine, while the Apify variant terminates silently without result (apart from an 'ok' / HTTP 200 return value).

Comment: Please note that I am aware that the `if (res) /* ... */ return /* ... */` is unecessary for Google Cloud Functions. It was just a quick way for me to test the exported function locally.

Comment: In your cloud function definition, what does your package.json contain?  My goal is to recreate your issue to see what happens on my project.

Comment: What does Apify.main return?  I doubt it's waiting for all that work to complete before moving on.

Comment: @Kolban The only dependency is `apify`. Everything else is defaults from `npm init`.

Comment: @DougStevenson You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `Apify.main()` function, it schedules the call to a later time, after your function already returned the result.

Comment: It indeed works. The parameter to `Apify.main()` has to return a `Promise` for it to wait until it resolves. Thanks!

Comment: Hum.  But then shouldn't it wait for the `async` function too? The doc mentions that `main` will wait, but it doesn't.

Comment: `Apify.main()` should only be used in stand-alone programs, but not inside server routes like in your case. There's no point to await `Apify.main()` if used in a stand-alone program.

Comment: Got it. My follow-up question would be: why? (i.e. what's in Apify.main that makes it so)

Comment: For details, please see `Apify.main()` docs at https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/apify#apifymainuserfunc