# Is there a way to use Apify.main() without it exiting the node.js process on completion?

Tags: apify

I'm using the Apify SDK in my app, and have written a number of scrapers using the Apify.main() function. The final action of main() is to exit the node process, but this does not suit my purposes. Is there any way to over-ride this behavior?

Comment: Relevant question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977763/how-to-use-apify-on-google-cloud-functions

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Apify.main` or <s>you can simply continue with code after it. `Apify.main` doesn't exit the process. The following code runs fully:</s>

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    console.log('main');
});
console.log('after main');
```

The main reasons for Apify.main are:

1) Ensure that the function inside it completes early so it doesn't wait on callbacks like your top-level code.

2) It emits some events.

Comment: Thanks lucas. As I understand it from the documentation (https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/apify#module_Apify.main) main() does exit the node.js process. When I run your code, this seems to be confirmed though it does log 'after main', but presumably that's because the main() function is async?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. It indeed exits the Node process. The reason why the `after main` log works in that I passed async function inside.