# Prevent Apify from shutting down my express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, apify

I have an express server with a `POST` endpoint that starts a crawler. When the crawler finishes it shuts down the whole server. Am I doing something wrong? How can I prevent it from happening?

The project looks something like this:

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const startSearch = require('./crawler.js')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/crawl', async (req, res) => {
  const { foo, bar } = req.body

  startSearch({ foo, bar })
  res.end()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

```js
// crawler.js
const Apify = require('apify')

const startSearch = ({ foo, bar }) => {
  Apify.main(async () => {
    const sources = [{
      url: 'https://path_to_website.com',
      userData: { foo, bar }
    }]
    const requestList = await Apify.openRequestList(null, sources)

    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
      requestList,
      handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
          // do things using puppeteer
        }
      }
    })

    await crawler.run()
  })
}
```

Comment: Just avoid using `Apify.main()`. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977763/how-to-use-apify-on-google-cloud-functions/56987370

Comment: Yep! that worked. Thanks! Feel free to answer and I'll validate it. Even though this is a duplicate I think there's value in keeping this question. I'd have never read the link you sent me just by reading the question, just because I'm not doing anything in Google Cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid using `Apify.main()`. For details, see [How to use Apify on Google Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977763/how-to-use-apify-on-google-cloud-functions/56987370)

(I thought I'm sending the answer, but it seems it was just a comment)

Comment: I just found out I missed your reply here! Validating and upvoting (almost 2 years later )